# Operator Overloading not extracting overrided value from file

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

So, I have hit quite a pickle. I'm trying to create 2 overloaded functions, one that inputs into a file using an insertion operator, and the other extracts the value from the file using an extraction operator.

Code Sample 1: Shows the class members.

```
    class OUSB          
{
private:

    unsigned short PORTB;

public:
    OUSB() { };

    char command[256];

    // Example of Interface methods (These can be changed....)
    unsigned short writePORTB(unsigned short newValue);

    unsigned short readPORTB();

    unsigned short runOUSBcommand(const char* command);

    // you may choose to implement operator overloaded functions for read and write functions for portb
    void operator<<(const unsigned short &val); // write portb
    void operator>>(unsigned short &val);       // read portb   
};
```

Code Sample 2: Shows the definition of each memeber or at least most of the members.

```
unsigned short OUSB::runOUSBcommand(const char* command)
{
    FILE* fpipe;
    char line[256];
    fpipe = (FILE*)_popen(command, "r"); // attempt to open pipe and execute a command 
    if (fpipe != NULL) // check that the pipe opened correctly
    {
        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fpipe))
        { // do nothing here, or print out debug data
        //cout << line; // print out OUSB data for debug purposes
        }
        _pclose(fpipe); // close pipe
    }
    else cout << "Error, problems with pipe!\n";
    int ousbOP = (int)atoi(line);
    return ousbOP;
}

void OUSB::operator<<(const unsigned short& val)
{
    OUSB hello;
    hello.writePORTB(val);
}

void OUSB::operator>>(unsigned short& val)
{
    OUSB hello;
    hello.readPORTB();
}

unsigned short OUSB::writePORTB(unsigned short newValue)
{

    sprintf_s(command, "ousb -r io portb %d", newValue);
    PORTB = runOUSBcommand(command);
    return PORTB;
}
    unsigned short OUSB::readPORTB()
{
    PORTB = runOUSBcommand("ousb -r io portb");
    return PORTB;
}
```

Code Sample 3: Finally, this is the piece of code that talks to the function, while inserting and extracting from the file

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //--- When no parameters MUST print id string in CSV format. 
    if (argc == 1)  // no parameters print this line.
    {
        cout << "3719632,s3719632@student.rmit.edu.au,Neshant_Thiru" << endl;

        OUSB command;
        unsigned short val = 3;
        command << val;       // write value to portb 

        command.writePORTB(8);  // write 8 to portb 

        command >> val;       // read portb and save to                             // variable value 

        cout << "value = " << val << endl;

    }
```

So within my main in the code sample above, you can see how `val = 3` is inserted into the file, and it is meant to be overridden by another value which is 8, as shown in `command.writePORTB(8)`.

Then the value extracted from file should display the overridden number 8. But instead, it still shows the value 3. 
So I'm really not sure, why its not extracting the overridden function.

P.S. I'm using a usb board called **OUSB** short of Open-Usb-io

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You store the value you read in a new object that you immmediately throw away, and you don't modify the argument.

You should let `*this` do the reading and writing, and you need to store the value in the argument when you read:

```
void OUSB::operator<<(const unsigned short& val)
{
    writePORTB(val);
}

void OUSB::operator>>(unsigned short& val)
{
    val = readPORTB();
}
```

Comment: I need your help, please tell me how can I contact you

Answer (score 0):

```
void OUSB::operator>>(unsigned short& val)
{
    OUSB hello;
    hello.readPORTB();
}
```

You don't use the argument `val` but discard the returned value of `hello.readPORTB()`. This error would be much easier to pick if you'd compile with all warnings enabled and by treating warnings as errors.